# What is the definition of "ROLE" in UNIVERSAL and how do Perl Roles work?

Tags: perl, roles, universal

Perl has an internal psuedo-module called `UNIVERSAL` which all modules inherit from. It has a method called `DOES`, from [the docs on `UNIVERSAL`](https://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html).

> `$obj->DOES( ROLE )`
>
> `CLASS->DOES( ROLE )`
>
> `DOES` checks if the object or class performs the role `ROLE`. A role is a named group of specific behavior (often methods of particular names and signatures), similar to a class, but not necessarily a complete class by itself. For example, logging or serialization may be roles.
>
> `DOES` and `isa` are similar, in that if either is true, you know that the object or class on which you call the method can perform specific behavior. However, `DOES` is different from `isa` in that it does not care how the invocand performs the operations, merely that it does. (`isa` of course mandates an inheritance relationship. Other relationships include aggregation, delegation, and mocking.)
>
> There is a relationship between roles and classes, as each class implies the existence of a role of the same name. There is also a relationship between inheritance and roles, in that a subclass that inherits from an ancestor class implicitly performs any roles its parent performs. Thus you can use `DOES` in place of `isa` safely, as it will return true in all places where `isa` will return true (provided that any overridden `DOES` and `isa` methods behave appropriately).

**I know Moose et al provide a `DOES`, and I understand how this is used.** But in the sense of `UNIVERSAL::DOES` what is a `ROLE`? How are they tracked? How are they created **aside from Moose** to satisfy `DOES`? I tried looking in the source, but [the implementation of `DOES` was not provided](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/perl-5.30.0/lib/UNIVERSAL.pm). Is this notion of a `ROLE` something in `CORE` perl? This seems to be related to the [`perldoc perlapi`'s mention of `sv_does_sv` (also `sv_does`/`sv_does_pv`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html)

> `sv_does_sv` Returns a `boolean` indicating whether the `SV` performs a specific, named role. The `SV` can be a Perl object or the name of a Perl class.
>
> `bool   sv_does_sv(SV* sv, SV* namesv, U32 flags)`

I can see a call to `sv_does_sv` in the [implementation of `universal.c`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/0a4d1779402e8824dd675302ad6a1914ea6ccf23/universal.c#L408). What's the definition of a SV role? Where can I find more information about this?

From the user-level, what does the code here do, (this is a subref)

```
UNIVERSAL->can('DOES')
```

The address returned is different from `UNIVERSAL->can('isa')` in the same invocation so it's doing something different, and I can see that muck in the above linked `universal.c`.

Comment: See for example [Role::Tiny line 443](https://metacpan.org/source/HAARG/Role-Tiny-2.000008/lib/Role/Tiny.pm#L443)

Comment: @choroba that's installing a custom `DOES`, which is what Moose does too. I'm asking about `UNIVERSAL::DOES` the non-custom one, and what the definition of a `ROLE` is in that context.

Comment: There's none. Each role implementation has to install its DOES to work.

Comment: @choroba so then what exactly does the code here do `UNIVERSAL->can("DOES")` do?

Comment: See also [Moxie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5U7eoeuO90)

Comment: It checks whether the package UNIVERSAL implements the subroutine DOES, and if it does, it returns the coderef.

Comment: @choroba and what does that coderef do? re: *"There's none."* Now we are on the same page, there is a default implementation -- what does it do? How does the default implementation work?

Comment: [UTSL](https://metacpan.org/source/XSAWYERX/perl-5.30.0/universal.c#L187). But it's getting too complex for me.

Comment: @choroba yep, saw that. I also saw the code in Universal.pm using that, but it's also too complex for me. I'm trying to grok it, but I wanted to ask the question first -- maybe someone has the fast and easy.

Comment: It isn't really correct to say that all modules inherit from `UNIVERSAL.pm`.  All packages inherit from the package `UNIVERSAL`, but the `UNIVERSAL.pm` module will only be loaded if someone specifically requests it with `use UNIVERSAL;` or similar.  While in the past, it was possible to import some functions from it, on modern versions of perl it is a no-op so there is no reason to ever load it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UNIVERSAL::DOES` is equivalent to:

```
sub DOES {
   croak "Usage: invocant->DOES(kind)"
       if @_ != 2;
   $_[0]->isa($_[1]);
}
```

Internally, `sv_does_sv` calls the `isa` method on the first SV it is passed.  perl itself doesn't provide an implementation of roles, so it is left to the role modules to provide a `DOES` that accounts for them.

The convention in Moose, Moo, Role::Tiny, Mouse, etc, is that the `DOES` method is true for class and its parent classes, and the roles that the class and its parent classes compose.  These libraries also provide the `does` method, which is only true for the composed roles of the class and its parent classes, but not class or its parent classes.